# Solving partial differential equations with the method of characteristics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

My  question is:

> Solve the partial differential equation: $$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = u$$
>   $$u(x,0)=\exp(x² + y²)$$

I'm used to deal with such equation when there are 2 variables (without $\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ )  using the method of characteristic.
I'm hoping to get some help here, any help would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial y} = u$$
$$u(x,y,0)=\exp(x² + y²)$$ 
Solving with the method of characteristics :
$$ \frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{1}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{u}$$
$x-t=c_1$ from $dx=dt$

$y-t=c_2$ from $dy=dt$

$\ln|u|-t=c_3$ from $\frac{du}{u}=dt$

The solution on implicit form is, with any differentiable function $\Phi$( _ , _ , _ ) :
$$\Phi\left((x-t),(y-t),\left(\ln|u|-t\right)\right)=0$$
This is equivalent to the explicit form, with any differentiable function $F$( _ , _ ):
$$\ln|u|-t=F\left((x-t),(y-t)\right)$$
Condition at $t=0$ :

$\ln|u|-0=F\left((x-0),(y-0)\right)=\ln|e^{x^2+y^2}|$
$$F(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$
Hense : $\ln|u|-t=(x-t)^2+(y-t)^2$
$$u(x,y,t)=e^{t+(x-t)^2+(y-t)^2}$$